# Entity Framework load data with left join lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to load from a specific id the list include details with lambda.

I tried it with following code:

```
// Load User Visitor list
var list = await Context.UserVisitors
                        .Where(s => s.UserId.Equals(userOwner.Id))
                        .Select(s => s.UserVisitorId)
                        .ToListAsync();

foreach (var t in list) 
{
     UserOwnerVisitors.Add(await Context.User
                                        .Include(u => u.Details)
                                        .Include(u => u.Settings)
                                        .FirstAsync(u => u.Id.Equals(t)));
}
```

The code works, but it is not efficient. How I can do it in one request with lambda?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have two "await"?  You only need one.

Comment: On the first await method, im fetching all ids of the user. After it, i'm loading the user data like settings, details into a list. I want to do it as one database query with one await. Currently im using a ugly foreach for quering data.

Comment: @TimoFalter there is a way to remove your foreach which would be something like this, in the last line: ....FirstAsync(u => list.Contains(u.Id).  that would remove your foreach.

Comment: However, if you want to really make one query to the database, you would need to perform a join operation through Linq

Comment: @Bruno Yes, that is right. I need a join operation, that is reason why i created this question. How I can do this?

Comment: @TimoFalter is there any navigation property in `User` to `UserVisitor` ?

Comment: @Progressive Yes. I'm experienting on Bruno solution.

Comment: @TimoFalter if you share your entity classes  (User, UserVisitor, UserOwnerVisitor), I can provide you a solution via linq lambda expressions

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit blind, as I don't know all your model's relationship, but below you can find what I think is your model, if you edit your question I can perhaps give you an exact answer:

```
var UserOwnerVisitorsList = from uv in Context.UserVisitors
                            join u in Context.User
                            on uv.UserId equals u.Id
                            join det in Context.Details
                            on det.UserId equals u.Id 
                            join set in Context.Settings
                            on set.UserId equals u.UserId
                            where uv.UserId == userOwner.Id
                            select u;
```